# Terminal in broken state (invisible text / no echo) after exit() during input() / raw_input()

Tags: python, terminal, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I've been writing a small utility application using Python 3 (the below testcase also works in Python 2, however) and PyQt 4 that uses the `code` module to spawn a REPL prompt allowing interaction with a Qt window.

Unfortunately I've hit a problem I've been unable to solve: When I `exit()` the app while `code` is inside `input()` (known as `raw_input()` in Python 2.x), my Linux terminal subsequently no longer echoes typed characters. I.e. the terminal appears to be left in a broken state, presumably due to some escape sequence issued by `input()`.

I've tried a variety of approaches to fix this, from using the `curses` module and other means to reset the terminal prior to running `exit`, to trying to emulate the `stdin` stream to exit by actually handing `exit()` to input() (unfornunately `code.InteractiveConsole.push()` does not work that way, as one might think it would), to trying to write my own non-blocking `input()` using `threading`, but I've been unable to pull together something working.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488275/python-terminal-text-becomes-invisible-after-subprocess), [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/782386), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340240/force-exit-from-readline-function) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1088234.html) are discussions of similar problems.

Finally, here is a reduced testcase to demonstrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import code
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

app.lastWindowClosed.connect(exit)

widget = QWidget()
widget.show()

code.interact()
```

For those unfamiliar with (Py)Qt, this will open a blank window, and when it is closed, the connection from `app`'s `lastWindowClosed` signal will cause a call to the built-in `exit()` function to happen. This occurs while the `code` module is executing a call to `input()` to read from `sys.stdin`. And here, when I close the window, typing into the terminal afterwards doesn't show any of the types characters.

I'm mainly using Python 3, and the actual app uses Python 3-specific code, but I've tried the testcase in Python 2.7 as well and it shows the same problem.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem in win7 64bit python26. If I close the qt frame the console brings again the normal prompt and I can enter text on it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm running this on Linux (I'll edit to mention that). The terminal behavior probably differs substantially between the platforms. Thanks for checking, though!

Answer (score 33):

Try `os.system('stty sane')`. The `stty sane` is supposed to reset echo, and some other things apparently.

Comment: Brilliant! The `stty sane` command is indeed getting the terminal out of *raw* mode without clearing the terminal itself which is what happens when using the `reset` command. Thanks!

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Indeed solves the problem.

Comment: Can confirm this works. For those who are new: You have to do this in the Python interpreter and `import os` first ;) One-liner to paste into a broken terminal is `import os; os.system('stty sane')`

Comment: is there a way to do this in native python without shelling out?

Comment: @ThorSummoner I don't think so. As far as I know python doesn't have much utilities for interacting with the terminal directly except for `raw_input()`. I don't even think it could do it without the core of python being modified just for that purpose. Maybe a module written in C could do it. Or an issue suggesting support for this could be submitted to the python repo.

Comment: +1 This also works for me when my MacOS terminal gets into a weird "noecho" state. I just type `stty sane` (though I can't see it) and everything is fine.

Answer (score 21):

This is no real solution to the problem, but
if you type "reset" in the terminal after you've closed the app, it goes back to normal.

I had similar issues once when developing a c application that didn't close a pipe correctly.
Maybe something similar is happening here aswell.

Comment: I have found that `reset` and `tput reset` are both not reliable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from [Quentin Engles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451600/quentin-engles) worked for me too but as a Python neophyte I didn't understand where the `stty sane` was supposed to go. After some hunting and head scratching I figured out that exit was a reference to the `exit()` method so I created `exiting()` and passed a reference to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import code
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget

def exiting():
    os.system('stty sane')
    exit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

app.lastWindowClosed.connect(exiting)

widget = QWidget()
widget.show()

code.interact()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to the same problem using the curses module. Using the other answer on this page, I've sidestepped the problem with `import os` at the beginning of the program, and then ending the program with `os.system('reset')`.

Comment: With curses, look into the [curses.wrapper()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) method. It sets up some of the most common curses settings and unsets them when your code ends, even if the program is killed by an exception.