# C - Signaling to another thread to cleanup and exit

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads, signals

This is not a homework problem, I promise.

I'm writing a time series database implementation as a way to learn C.

I have a client/server pair that I've written. The server is currently an echo server listening to a socket on a port. The client connects to that port and sends lines of input to it. It uses `readline` to get input, `send`s it to the client socket, `recv`s a line from the client socket, and prints the line to the terminal. Rinse, repeat. The client returns when it gets an `EOF` from `recv`, at which point it knows the connection is closed.

The problem is that `readline` is blocking, such that if the server process is killed, i.e. I `SIGINT` it, the client is still blocking on `readline`. It isn't until after it `send`s, then `recv`s an `EOF`, that it will know the server is gone.

What I **want** to happen is for the client to get signaled if there's an `EOF` on `recv` and immediately exit.

What I *think* I need to do is to create 3 `pthreads` - 2 for a network client (`send` and `recv`) and 1 for the terminal. The terminal calls `readline` and blocks. It accepts input, and then uses a `pthread_cond_t` to signal the waiting network client `send` thread to send. The network client `recv` thread is constantly `recv`ing, which will block. If it is an `EOF`, it raises `SIGINT`, the handler to which `pthread_kill`s all 3 threads, `fprintf`s something like "Connection closed by server.", and calls `exit` (yes, I know `exit` will terminate all threads anyways - it's an exercise in cleanliness and to see if I understand C).

Is this the appropriate approach? Obviously network client terminals do this all the time. What's the right approach?

Comment: There is no one correct approach. The classic reference is Rich Stevens' [_UNIX Network Programming_](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551)

Comment: "*It uses readline to get input ...*" "*it*" is who, the client or the server?

Comment: And: One does not send "*to a socket*" but "*via*" a socket "*to*" some destination (here the client the server), as mostly the socket is used bi-directional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered before. I got Stevens and chapter 5 suggested interleaving the `readline` call with a socket `read` to look for `EOF`. I did a Google search for `libreadline` and `select`/`poll` and saw this:

[Interrupting c/c++ readline with signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290411/interrupting-c-c-readline-with-signals)

There's a way to use interleave I/O so `libreadline` doesn't just block:

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html

Thanks @arayq2 and @G-- for suggesting Stevens!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you would like to exit during a `readline`, which is before your `write()`/`send()`, when the server dies. Your approach is fine. The only way you will catch if the server has died is when you try to `write()`/`send()` you'll get a `SIGPIPE` which will cause an exit right after it. Because by default, no packets are sent on the connection unless there is data to send or acknowledge. So, if you are simply waiting for data from the peer, there is no way to tell if the peer has silently gone away, or just isn't ready to send/receive any more data yet. So you would need some poller for the `SIGPIPE` in a separate thread and exit when you get it. You could use this `readline` function to help you get started with the checking.

```
/**
 * Simple utility function that reads a line from a file descriptor fd, 
 * up to maxlen bytes -- ripped from Unix Network Programming, Stevens.
 */
int
readline(int fd, char *buf, int maxlen)
{
    int n, rc;
    char c;

    for (n = 1; n < maxlen; n++) {
    if ((rc = read(fd, &c, 1)) == 1) {
        *buf++ = c;
        if (c == '\n')
        break;
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        if (n == 1)
        return 0; // EOF, no data read
        else
        break; // EOF, read some data
    } else
        return -1; // error
    }

    *buf = '\0'; // null-terminate
    return n;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. FWIW, a coworker said that calling `read` for each char is highly inefficient, because each call has to be trapped by the kernel. I don't know if that's true, and if so, what impact that has. In any case, I'm actually using `libreadline` to get the built in ctrl character functionality. I'll check out Stevens.