# Portably exit readline from C++11 thread with SDL2

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2, readline

Consider a simple program: (require `-std=c++11 -lpthread -lreadline -lSDL2` when compile with g++ with pthread)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <cstdlib>
extern "C" {
#include <readline/readline.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", 0, 0, 200, 200, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    std::thread console([](){
        while (true) {
            char *console_input_c_str = readline("> ");
            if (console_input_c_str == NULL)
                break;
            std::cout << "line: " << console_input_c_str << '\n';
            std::free(console_input_c_str);
        }
    });

    while (true) {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        std::cerr << "received event type "<<event.type<<'\n';
        if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT &&
                event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
            break;
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    console.join();
}
```

The main thread creates a window `window` with SDL2, enter a SDL event loop, while the thread `console` repeatedly read from the console using `readline`. When the window is exited, it waits for the console thread to finish then exit.

The program works fine; however, **how can I make the console thread to stop when the window is exited?**

It's fine if the program only use a single thread. It's also fine if exiting the console readline quits the program.

---

[Exit readline is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340240/force-exit-from-readline-function), but there is a problem with all the answers there - `pthread_kill` or `reset -Q` is not portable.

[Terminating a thread is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207684/how-do-i-terminate-a-thread-in-c11) (using `std::terminate` or `.detach()`), but the console is left in a bad state because `readline` don't terminate normally. To reset the console it's possible to use `reset -Q`, but that's not portable.

Using readline's alternative (async) interface doesn't work because SDL don't listen for events on the console. Using `select` is also not portable.

Comment: In short: It's not possible to do in a totally platform agnostic and portable way. Use [`SDL_PollEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) and [the alternate interface](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC41) together with conditional compilation to use either `select` or some Windows-specific polling.

Comment: Replace while(true) in it with while(no_need_to_end_this_thread)?

Comment: @ÖöTiib The major problem is that the call to `readline()` is *blocking*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then he can use platform-specific non-blocking console functions (like _kbhit() or getch()), no standard C++ functions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `readline` is not completely blocking, it calls `rl_event_hook` every 1/10 seconds (by default). It's possible to check whether the program is stopped inside the event hook, and if so do a `longjmp` or `throw` to get out of the function (in this example `int` is used, although it's possible to define your own exception class):

```
std::atomic<bool> stopped (false);

rl_event_hook = [](){
    if (stopped)
        throw 0;
    return 0;
};

try {
    /* something calls readline() */
} catch (int) {
    rl_cleanup_after_signal();
}
return 0;
```

or by setting `rl_done = 1`: (this won't work when `rl_event_hook` is `nullptr`. Also note that `rl_event_hook` is not called when a key is held, it's necessary to override `rl_getc_function` to change the behavior. It's [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020171/how-undefined-a-race-condition-can-be) to modify `rl_done` from the other thread)

```
std::atomic<bool> stopped (false);

rl_event_hook = [](){
    if (stopped)
        rl_done = true;
    return 0;
};

/* something calls readline() */
if (stopped) return 0;
/* process */
return 0;
```

and in the main thread use:

```
stopped = true;
console.join();
```